# When creating a pricing page for my Android App, how do you set price based on Country?

Tags: android, price

My App has different prices for different countries. In India for example, the price will be lower as compared to US Customers.

This is possible for Google Playstore
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9306917

**My Problem**

I have a pricing page inside the App which shows the price before the user buys.

I want this price to reflect the different prices set in the Google Playstore by country

How do I do this?

I assume there must either be a way for me to => Know which country the user is based on info from the Playstore and hard code it  **OR** Have an API to get price from the Playstore.

Comment: It depends on the language you are using to code this with. Are you talking about in app purchases using the Google Play Billing library?